# How do you :tag: every word of a line using substitution?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, tags, plugin-vimwiki

How do you substitute every word of a line, so that it becomes a useful **vimwiki** tag?

Provided the following line:

```
Word Compund_Word
```

I want:

```
:Word: :Compund_Word:
```

I guess it involves some use of **regex**, but I haven't been able to figure out which string.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While on the line in question:

```
:s/\w\+/:&:/g
```

**Breakdown**

- `\w\+` will match 1 or more word characters (`[0-9A-Za-z_]`).
- `&` has a special meaning in a replacement, depending on the value of `'magic'` (default: on). It is replaced with the
  matched pattern.
- the `g` flag will perform this substitution for every occurrence on
  the line, not just the first.

**Non-ASCII use**

- To use any non-whitespace character as a word character use `\S`:

  ```
  :s/\S\+/:&:/g
  ```
- To use any character *except* specific delimiters, use `[^{delimiters}]` (substituting
  `{delimiters}` with any number of delimiters):

  ```
  :s/[^;,|]\+/:&:/g
  ```

See:

```
:h /\w
:h /\+
:h sub-replace-special
:h 'magic'
:h :s_flags
:h :s_g
```

Comment: Thanks to Jake Grossman's answer, I realized how it had to be done. For the sake of completion, I added instructions to non-ASCII use.

Comment: @Ludenticus You can also use `\S` to match any non-bank character...

Answer (score 1):

Vimwiki also allows you to list all the tags together, with a single `:` separating multiple tags, such as in:

```
:Word:Compund_Word:Other_Tag:
```

To accomplish this replacement, you can use a `:s` command that will replace a sequence of whitespace with a single `:`, and additionally match the beginning and end of the line to insert an extra `:` on each end.

You can perform that substitution on a specific line with:

```
:s/^\s*\zs\|\s\+\|\ze\s*$/:/g
```

See [`:help /\zs`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs) and [`:help /\ze`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cze) to understand how the matches for the start and end of the line work... The match for whitespace between words should be easy to grasp.